# SQL Developer / SQLPLUS login to Oracle 12c DB using AD credentials through Kerberos

Tags: database, oracle, active-directory, oracle-sqldeveloper, kerberos

I'm totally new to Oracle and have been tasked with setting up 12c for a class a professor is teaching next semester. He wants the students to be able to use their AD accounts to access the database they'll be working on. I looked at available options, and without extending the AD schema, kerberos looked to be my only option.

I tried following a combination of these:

http://www.ateam-oracle.com/configuring-your-oracle-database-for-kerberos-authentication/

https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DBSEG/asokerb.htm#DBSEG9646

In terms of the Oracle documentation above, my process is breaking down on step 8. After step 7 (which I performed on a domain controller), when I attempt to login to SQLPLUS with SYSTEM account, I was receiving:
ORA-12641: Authentication service failed to initialize
If I try to connect with the SYSTEM (or Active Directory) account through SQL DEVELOPER I get this:
Listener refused the connection with the following error: ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in the connect descriptor

So I added NTS back to SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES, but the problem persists. On top of that, Enterprise Manager Express (https://:5500/em) is also no longer accessible.

This same thing happened the first time I tried stepping through the available documentation, and I managed to get everything back to a default by deleting sqlnet.ora, listerner.ora and starting from scratch... But now I'm back in the same place again.

If it is helpful, here are the contents of sqlnet.ora:

#

```
SQLNET.KERBEROS5_KEYTAB = c:\Windows\oracle.keytab
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (BEQ, TCPS, KERBEROS5, NTS)
SQLNET.KERBEROS5_CONF = c:\Windows\krb5.ini
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_KERBEROS5_SERVICE = oracle
SQLNET.KERBEROS5_CC_NAME=OSMSFT:
ADR_BASE = D:\app\oracle\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\log
```

#

I did comment out SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES = (BEQ, TCPS, KERBEROS5, NTS) which I allowed me to login with the built-in accounts again, and brought Enterprise Manager Express back up.

Any guidance on this is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I also looked at these: https://bjornnaessens.wordpress.com/2012/12/21/configuring-kerberos-for-oracle-databases-11-2-with-win2008r2-ad/#comments

http://vanbortel.blogspot.com/2010/09/single-sign-on-to-database-or-wna-for.html

Comment: If your client is already integrated in a kerberos realm, there is not much of setup to do there., just set sqlnet authentication services to also support KERBEROS5. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/dbseg/integrating_mads_with_oracle_database.html#GUID-9739D541-FA9D-422A-95CA-799A4C6F488D has some nice directions how to configure the database server. Again, if that server is already integrated, just add a SPN for oracle, add the credentials to the wallet and off you go.